# Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix

Tags: android

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#F0A0A0A0"/>
    **<stroke android:width="2dp" color="#A00080FF"/>**
    <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="0dp"
        android:right="5dp" android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

I get the above error on the bold lines. "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
  <stroke android:width="2dp" color="#A00080FF"/>
```

should be

```
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#A00080FF"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

use android:color="#A00080FF"

instead of color="#A00080FF"

Sample::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
     <gradient android:startColor="#DD000000" android:endColor="#DD2ECCFA" 
            android:angle="225"/> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```